# linux live on SD card - booting with persistence automatically

Tags: linux, grub, liveusb, persistence

i am running a live debian distro with persistence off an SD card with linux live. this is all working fine, but in order to boot with persistence, i must currently press TAB and manually type in persistence when presented with the boot menu.

is it possible do have this done automatically, off an SD card running linux live?

peace,

faustus

FOR THOSE WONDERING WHAT THE BOTHER IS: i'm running off a laptop with a cracked screen and parts of the keyboard no longer working. typing persistence involves me plugging in a keyboard, typing in, and unplugging it again. i run a remote desktop in order to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try editing /boot/grub/grub.cfg on the SD.
Add the word "persistence" to the kernel line (lines beginning with "linux") you are booting from.
Hope this helps!

Comment: in the past, on linux that i had installed onto my HD, i do recall being able to edit this file perfectly fine. however, on the live linux this file path doesn't exist. if it's of any relevance, i used LinuxLive USB Creator to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, better later than never :}
Your Debian live might use Syslinux (not Grub) to boot.
You can check this by looking if there's a `/syslinux` or `/isolinux` at the root of your SD card filesystem.
If it's the case you can use samhain1138's advice and add `persistence` on the `*.cfg` file in the isolinux/syslinux directory that loads your live-system. e.g. for `live.cfg`:

```
append boot=live persistence config quiet splash
```